# regex with corresponding pipes in match and substitution strings

Tags: regex, matlab

Is it possible to use corresponding `or` operators (`|`) in the match and substitution strings of a regex substitution, such that a list of different possible matches is replaced by a corresponding list of different substitution strings? For instance,

```
perl -e '$str="word1"; $str=~s/1/2/; print $str."\n"'
  word2
perl -e '$str="word3"; $str=~s/3/4/; print $str."\n"'
  word4

perl -e '$str="word1"; $str=~s/1|3/2|4/; print $str."\n"'
  word2          (actual output: word2|4)
perl -e '$str="word3"; $str=~s/1|3/2|4/; print $str."\n"'
  word4          (actual output: word2|4)
```

The last two statements give fictitious (desired) output (the real output is shown in parentheses).

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Matlab to give you any sort of reliable answer but bullet 3 might be of interest: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexprep.html#f76-1152246

Comment: It doesn't make sense. What exactly do you do to the first two to get the second two?

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort. Your suggestions in other languages were great, by the way.

Comment: @Phonon: Sorry if my question is unclear. The first two show that if the string is "word1" it gets replaced by "word2," and if it is "word3" it gets replaced by "word4". The last two statements show a pseudo-command that will handle either string appropriately (i.e., a single command that will convert "word1" to "word2" or "word3" to "word4".

Comment: @Phonon: user001 is looking for the Matlab version of Perl's `%m = (1 => 2, 3 => 4); $s = "word1"; $s =~ s/1|3/$m{$&}/` or Ruby's `m = { '1' => '2', '3' => '4' }; 'word1'.gsub(/1|2/) { m[$&] }` or JavaScript's `m = { 1: 2, 3: 4 }; 'word1'.replace(/1|2/, function(x) { return m[x] });`

Comment: @muistooshort: The bullet you referred me to was precisely what I was looking for. You should post it as the solution. Thanks!

`str_match = cell(2,1); str_match{1}='1'; str_match{2}='3';
str_sub = cell(2,1); str_sub{1}='2'; str_sub{2}='4';
regexprep('word1',str_match,str_sub); regexprep('word3',str_match,str_sub);`

Comment: Go ahead and put that down as an answer yourself (you can answer your own questions and accept those answers), I don't mind, I'm just happy to see the problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits go to user **mu is too short**.

Regular expression substitution using multiple matched input patterns and output strings is achieved in Matlab as shown in the following example.

```
str_match = cell(2,1); str_match{1}='1'; str_match{2}='3';
str_sub = cell(2,1); str_sub{1}='2'; str_sub{2}='4';
regexprep('word1',str_match,str_sub)
    ans = word2
regexprep('word3',str_match,str_sub)
    ans = word4
```